# How to list down all the soft links only inside a directory in Linux systems

Tags: linux

What is a shortcut command to list all the links inside a directory in linux machines. I can list all files and folders and copy output in a temp file and from there I can do a grep, but what I am looking for is a shortcut command to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

> and copy output in a temp file

This is exactly the situation for pipes!

```sh
ls -la | grep "^l"
```

The `stdout` of `ls -la` is redirected to the input of `grep`. It sounds like you know, but just for completeness the `"^l"` is a regular expression that searches for an `l` at the start of a line.

Comment: This is also very useful as well. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1.Open a terminal and move to that directory.
2.Type the command: ls -la. This shall long list all the files in the directory       ` even if they are hidden.
3.The files that start with l are your symbolic link files.